# Why does Eclipse want to download a previous version of Gradle when I already have a later version installed?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to import a project from GitHub to Eclipse. I have `Nodeeclipse` and `Gradle` installed. I already have `Gradle 2.4` package installed but when I begin to import it, Eclipse starts to download `Gradle 2.1` and fails.

How can I make it recognize and use `Gradle 2.4`?

Comment: Well, If the gradle project was developed for gradle 2.1 it downloads it. How can it know that your version is fully compatible with all the plugins used in the project for gradle 2.1?

Comment: Formatting for readability and clarifying the title